# Use R to translate 'coded' table

Tags: r

I have a problem with using **R** to 'translate' back a coded table. So I have a table with table elements consisting of XX,XY,YY. I have a second table (.csv) with the proper meaning of the X and Y - so it might look like, if X=1 and Y=2,

XY is transformed into 12
XX is transformed into 11 ...

can anybody hint at a good starting point to write such a program/ piece of code in **R**?

Comment: Try this http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/03/lookup-performance-in-r.html

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly different than a lookup table in that you're actually regexing and replacing parts of each element.  The qdap (Quantitative Discourse Analysis Package) has a `mgsub` (multiple `gsub`) function that can handle this easily.

```
library(qdap)

#recreate scenerio with quick character vector (no need for quotes)
z <- factor(qcv(XX,XY,YY))  
#replace all X and Ys with 1 and 2
mgsub(pattern = c("X", "Y"), replacement = c(1, 2), text.var = z)


#Even better if you have the code book read in, say it looks like this:
code.book <- data.frame(symb = c("X", "Y"), replacement = c(1, 2))

# > code.book
#   symb replacement
# 1    X           1
# 2    Y           2

mgsub(code.book$symb, code.book$replacement, z)
```

Comment: hey..that's awesome..The only thing is I might have not made exactly clear that each element in the table has another translation. So for elements [1,3] which is names XY the translation would not be 12 but they translate into other values such as 56....

Comment: I think you'll have to edit your original answer and be more explicit showing a sample in put, the code book and the desired output.